# Is it possible to create a TikZ calendar with very few dates (which are very apart)?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-calendar

Is it possible to produce a TikZ Calendar without the range option? Would it be possible to enter very few dates manually as in a LaTeX list environment? More exactly:

**Is it possible to to display dates for which there are no events associated to?**

Comment: You can format some days manually. For example `if (Tuesday) [red]` or `if (equals=2014-03-3)[black!20,nodes={thick,draw=red!50}]`. So, if you specify the range and use white color you can highlight some dates.

Comment: @Sigur but how can we **supress** some dates where nothing is happening? For the time being I decided to use `\begin{description} \item[6-6-2014] Event! \end{description}` instead of the calendar.

Comment: Don't you want a blank space there? You want to remove the empty dates?

Comment: Yes: I edited the question to make it clear.

Comment: It is not clear what you want. Please, try to post your actual document so we can see the output. Based on your bold statement I guess that you are only showing dates with events!

Comment: @Sigur:  I have only dates with events but I would like to have the months being displayed as well. I will edit the question.

Comment: See my answer below. Adjust it to your case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not an answer but you could try to adapt it.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[margin=1cm,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}
[every day/.style={anchor=mid},every node/.style={inner sep=2pt,rectangle,thick}]
\calendar (cal) [dates=2014-02-01 to 2014-07-last, month list, month label left,%
month text=\textcolor{black}{\%mt}, month yshift=1.7em, black!20]
%
if (Tuesday) [black]
if (Friday) [black]
%
if (at most=2014-03-05) [black!20]
%
if (equals=2014-03-3)[black!20,nodes={thick,draw=red!50}]
if (equals=2014-03-4)[black!20,nodes={thick,draw=red!50}]
%
if (equals=2014-04-26) [black!20] 
if (equals=2014-04-27) [blue,nodes={thick,draw=blue}] 
if (equals=2014-06-28) [black!20] 
%
if (Saturday) [style={font=\slshape\selectfont}]
if (Sunday)   [style={font=\slshape\selectfont}]
%
if (at least=2014-07-15) [black!20]
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]