# Filter dates in a Tikz calendar

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-calendar

**Context**

I have many (~20+) dates (or ranges) *of interest*  dispatched over  a 5 year `calendar`.

So much wasted space !

[image]

**My question**

[calendar-with-very-few-dates](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183547/is-it-possible-to-create-a-tikz-calendar-with-very-few-dates-which-are-very-apa) helped a bit (to (light)color the "useless" dates) but **how can I have a filtered calendar below where i'd get the month only if there is a date used in it?**

In the example above, the calendar goes from may 2018 to august 2022. It corresponds to 52 rows, 52 months.  However 44 of these 52 rows are "empty" in the way none of my inputed dates are represented there.
As a result, I'd like to get the same display by month but i'd get only 8 rows of months.

```
May18
Jun18
Jul18
Jul19
Jul20
Jul21
Jul22
Aug22
```

to get something closer to
[image]

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,tikz]{standalone}
%\usepackage[french]{babel}
%\usepackage[french]{translator}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar}

\makeatletter

\pgfkeys{/pgf/calendar/start of year/.code={%
    \ifnum\pgfcalendarifdateday=1\relax%
        \ifnum\pgfcalendarifdatemonth=1\relax\pgfcalendarmatchestrue\fi%
    \fi%
}}%

% Define our own style
\tikzset{week list sunday/.style={execute at begin day scope={%
        % Because for TikZ Monday is 0 and Sunday is 6,
        % we can't directly use \pgfcalendercurrentweekday,
        % but instead we define \c@pgf@counta (basically) as:
        % (\pgfcalendercurrentweekday + 1) % 7
        \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@x{\tikz@lib@cal@xshift}%
        \ifnum\pgfcalendarcurrentweekday=6
            \c@pgf@counta=0
        \else
            \c@pgf@counta=\pgfcalendarcurrentweekday
            \advance\c@pgf@counta by 1
        \fi
        \pgf@x=\c@pgf@counta\pgf@x
        % Shift to the right position for the day.
        \pgftransformxshift{\pgf@x}
    }},
    tikz@lib@cal@width=7}

% New style for drawing the year, it is always drawn
% for January

\tikzset{year label left/.style={    
    execute before day scope={
        \ifdate{start of year}{
            \drawyear
            }{}
    },
    % Right align
    every year/.append style={
        anchor=east,
        xshift=-6em
    }},
    N_date/.style={circle,very thick,draw=red}
    }


% This actually draws the year.
\newcommand{\drawyear}{
    \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@x}{\tikz@lib@cal@xshift}%
    \pgftransformxshift{-\pgf@x}
    % \tikzyearcode is defined by default
    \tikzyearcode
    \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@x}{\tikz@lib@cal@xshift}%
    \pgftransformxshift{\pgf@x}
}

\makeatother

% I define my dates of interest


\def\SCal{2018-05-01}
\def\ECal{2022-08-last}
\def\SNego{2018-05-11}
\def\ENego{2018-06-11}
\def\Deal{2018-06-12}
\def\PreStrike{2018-06-12}
\def\Issue{2018-06-27}
\def\SComm{2018-06-28}
\def\EComm{2018-07-28}
\def\Strike{2018-07-29}
\def\ConstatOne{2019-07-29}
\def\ConstatTwo{2020-07-29}
\def\ConstatThree{2021-07-29}
\def\ConstatFour{2022-07-29}
\def\ConstatFive{2022-07-29}
\def\FinalValue{2022-07-29}
\def\Maturity{2022-08-10}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
        
    \calendar (CalPS)[
        dates=\SCal to \ECal,
        year label left,
        every year/.append style={font=\Large\sffamily\bfseries,
        orange!50!black},
        month list, 
        month label left, 
        month yshift=1.25em,
        days={
            gray!20,
            text width=width("00"),
            align=center,
            %       inner xsep=
            %       .5*\csname tikz@lib@cal@xshift\endcsname-.5*\csname tikz@text@width\endcsname,
            %       inner ysep=.5*\csname tikz@lib@cal@month@yshift\endcsname-.5*height("0")
        }
    ]
    %---------- Phase 1 ------------------------------
    if (between=\SNego and \ENego)  [days={fill=green!50}]
    %---------- Phase 2 ------------------------------
    if (equals=\Deal) [days={fill=green!80,rectangle}, red]
    %---------- Phase 3------------------------------
    if (equals=\PreStrike) [days={fill=red!80,rectangle}]
    %---------- Phase 4 ------------------------------
    if (equals=\Issue) [days={fill=blue!80,rectangle}]
    %---------- Phase 5------------------------------
    if (between=\SComm and \EComm)  [days={fill=green!90}]
    %---------- Phase 6------------------------------
    if (equals=\Strike) [days={fill=red!80,rectangle}]
    %---------- Phase 7 ------------------------------
    if (    equals=\ConstatOne,
    equals=\ConstatTwo,
    equals=\ConstatThree,
    equals=\ConstatFour,
    equals=\ConstatFive,
    ) [days={fill=orange!80,rectangle}]
    %---------- Phase 8 ------------------------------
    if (equals=\FinalValue) [days={fill=red!80,rectangle}]
    %---------- Phase 9 ------------------------------
    if (equals=\Maturity) [days={fill=blue!80,rectangle}]
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

NB: Is it just me or did I notice most `calendar` examples on TexSE where pretty old with `Tikzstyle` in it ?

Comment: I am not sure if what you are asking defeats the purpose of a calendar. If we were to remove all unused dates, how will this be different from just a list of the important events?

Comment: Heheheh you're right. Let me rephrase. I'd like to keep the 8 months (in my example) when you have a date populated for that month.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat May i ask you where I should look at (posts ? parts of the manual?) to implement the filter on the calendar ?

Comment: Honestly, I do not know, I do not even understand the question completely.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Understood, I edited my question to precise it.

Comment: Thanks! Let's hope some expert shows up. (I have almost no idea how these calendars work, and am a bit overwhelmed by the large number of macros that are defined in the beginning. They will make it hard for anyone who is not very familiar with these calendars to keep track of what's going on.)

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat what ? there is something you don't know  ? :) That's when I know it's the limit to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the library having any interface to skip dates especially not months where no `if` applies. You'd need alter `\ifdate` to collect all dates so that you can look those up at the start of the month/year.

My solution checks wther the current month/year is in the list of to-be-skipped dates and then just skips right to the last day of the month/year and not do anything for that first day of the skipped month/year.

I rewrote `month list` as `month list with skipped months` which takes two arguments:

1. whole years that are to be skipped and
2. months that are to be skipped

I didn't use years and I haven't tested it at all, soooo good luck with that.
The months are given in a list-like format so that following months don't need to be given manually:

```
month list with skipped months={}{
  2018:8 to 12,
  2019:1 to  6,
  2019:8 to 12,
  2020:1 to  6,
  2020:8 to 12,
  2021:2 to  6, % kept January in to test a proper start of the year
  2021:8 to 12,
  2022:1 to  6
},
```

We need to shift a few times in the *y* direction because we have to counteract the downshifting that is done at the first of the month which we didn't do while we're checking for the skip.

I don't like it but it is the cleanest I've come up with.

The code

```
every month/.append code=\ifdate{skipped month}{\pgfkeysalso{shape=coordinate}}{},
```

is used to hide skipped months' names.

### Code

```
\documentclass[12pt,tikz,convert]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar}

\pgfset{
  calendar/start of year/.code={% check for start of year
    \ifnum\pgfcalendarifdateday=1\relax%
        \ifnum\pgfcalendarifdatemonth=1\relax\pgfcalendarmatchestrue\fi%
    \fi}}
\tikzset{% setting up the collections, used by month list with skipped months
  skipper/setup year skips/.style={
    /utils/exec=\def\listSkipYear{,},
    skipper/years/.list={#1}},
  skipper/years/.code=%
    \edef\listSkipYear{\listSkipYear#1,},
  skipper/setup month skips/.style={
    /utils/exec=\def\listSkipMonth{,},
    skipper/months/.list={#1}},
  skipper/months/.style args={#1:#2to#3}{
    skipper/@/.code=%
      \edef\listSkipMonth{\listSkipMonth#1-\ifnum##1<10 0\fi##1,},
    skipper/@/.list={#2,...,#3}},
}
\makeatletter
\pgfset{% \ifdate lookups for year or year-months
  calendar/skipped year/.code=%
    \edef\pgf@cal@temp{{,\pgfcalendarifdateyear,}{\listSkipYear}}%
    \expandafter\pgfutil@in@\pgf@cal@temp
    \let\ifpgfcalendarmatches\ifpgfutil@in@,
  calendar/skipped month/.code=%
    \edef\pgf@cal@temp
      {{,\pgfcalendarifdateyear-\pgfcalendarifdatemonth,}{\listSkipMonth}}%
    \expandafter\pgfutil@in@\pgf@cal@temp
    \let\ifpgfcalendarmatches\ifpgfutil@in@
}

\newif\ifSkipDay
\tikzset{
  month list with skipped months/.style 2 args={%
    skipper/setup year skips={#1},
    skipper/setup month skips={#2},
    every month/.append code=%
      \ifdate{skipped month}{\pgfkeysalso{shape=coordinate}}{},
    execute before day scope={%
      \SkipDayfalse
      \ifdate{day of month=1}{% do the test only on the first of the month
        \ifdate{skipped year}{% skip straight to the nye
          \pgfcalendardatetojulian
            {\pgfcalendarcurrentyear-12-31}\pgfcalendarcurrentjulian
          \SkipDaytrue
        }{%
          \ifdate{equals=\pgfcalendarbeginiso}{% start of the calendar is never skipped
            \drawyear % every first (even the very first) we shift down, counteract %
            \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@y}{\tikz@lib@cal@month@yshift}%                  %
            \pgftransformyshift{+\pgf@y}%                                           %
            \begingroup % from original month list style %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
              \c@pgf@counta=\pgfcalendarcurrentjulian%                 %
              \advance\c@pgf@counta by-\pgfcalendarcurrentday%         %
              \advance\c@pgf@counta by1\relax%                         %
              \pgfcalendarjuliantoweekday{\c@pgf@counta}{\c@pgf@countb}%
              \xdef\pgf@temp{\the\c@pgf@countb}%                       %
            \endgroup                                                  %
            \let\tikz@lib@cal@month@list@start=\pgf@temp%              %
          }{%
            \ifdate{start of year}{%
              \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@y}{\tikz@lib@cal@month@yshift}%
              \pgftransformyshift{+-\pgf@y}%
              \drawyear % every first (even the very first) we shift down, counteract %
              \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@y}{\tikz@lib@cal@month@yshift}%                  %
              \pgftransformyshift{+\pgf@y}%                                           %
            }{}%
          }%
          \ifdate{skipped month}{%
            \pgfcalendardatetojulian
              {\pgfcalendarcurrentyear-\pgfcalendarcurrentmonth-last}%
              \pgfcalendarcurrentjulian
            \SkipDaytrue
          }{}%
         }%
      }{}%
      %
      \ifSkipDay\else
        \ifdate{day of month=1}{% from original month list style %%%%%%%%%
          \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@y}{\tikz@lib@cal@month@yshift}%         %
          \pgftransformyshift{+-\pgf@y}%                                 %
          \edef\tikz@lib@cal@month@list@start{\pgfcalendarcurrentweekday}%
        }{}%
      \fi
    },%
    execute at begin day scope={% from original month list style %
      \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@xa{\tikz@lib@cal@xshift}%            %
      \pgf@xb=\pgfcalendarcurrentday\pgf@xa%                     %
      \advance\pgf@xb by\tikz@lib@cal@month@list@start\pgf@xa%   %
      \advance\pgf@xb by-\pgf@xa\relax%                          %
      \pgftransformxshift{\pgf@xb}%                              %
    },                                                           %
    tikz@lib@cal@width=37                                        %
  },
}

% This actually draws the year.
\newcommand{\drawyear}{
    \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@x}{\tikz@lib@cal@xshift}%
    \pgftransformxshift{-\pgf@x}
    % \tikzyearcode is defined by default
    \tikzyearcode
    \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@x}{\tikz@lib@cal@xshift}%
    \pgftransformxshift{\pgf@x}
}
\makeatother

% I define my dates of interest
\def\SCal{2018-05-01}
\def\ECal{2022-08-last}
\def\SNego{2018-05-11}
\def\ENego{2018-06-11}
\def\Deal{2018-06-12}
\def\PreStrike{2018-06-12}
\def\Issue{2018-06-27}
\def\SComm{2018-06-28}
\def\EComm{2018-07-28}
\def\Strike{2018-07-29}
\def\ConstatOne{2019-07-29}
\def\ConstatTwo{2020-07-29}
\def\ConstatThree{2021-07-29}
\def\ConstatFour{2022-07-29}
\def\ConstatFive{2022-07-29}
\def\FinalValue{2022-07-29}
\def\Maturity{2022-08-10}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \calendar (CalPS)[
        dates=\SCal to \ECal,
        every year/.append style={
          font=\sffamily\bfseries, orange!50!black, anchor=base east, xshift=-6em},
        month list with skipped months={}{
          2018:8 to 12,
          2019:1 to  6,
          2019:8 to 12,
          2020:1 to  6,
          2020:8 to 12,
          2021:2 to  6,
          2021:8 to 12,
          2022:1 to  6
        },
        month label left, 
        month yshift=1.25em,
        days={gray!20, text width=width("00"), align=center}
    ]
    %---------- Phase 1 ------------------------------
    if (between=\SNego and \ENego)  [days={fill=green!50}]
    %---------- Phase 2 ------------------------------
    if (equals=\Deal) [days={fill=green!80,rectangle}, red]
    %---------- Phase 3------------------------------
    if (equals=\PreStrike) [days={fill=red!80,rectangle}]
    %---------- Phase 4 ------------------------------
    if (equals=\Issue) [days={fill=blue!80,rectangle}]
    %---------- Phase 5------------------------------
    if (between=\SComm and \EComm)  [days={fill=green!90}]
    %---------- Phase 6------------------------------
    if (equals=\Strike) [days={fill=red!80,rectangle}]
    %---------- Phase 7 ------------------------------
    if (equals=\ConstatOne,
        equals=\ConstatTwo,
        equals=\ConstatThree,
        equals=\ConstatFour,
        equals=\ConstatFive,
    ) [days={fill=orange!80,rectangle}]
    %---------- Phase 8 ------------------------------
    if (equals=\FinalValue) [days={fill=red!80,rectangle}]
    %---------- Phase 9 ------------------------------
    if (equals=\Maturity) [days={fill=blue!80,rectangle}];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]